# HostName Cannot be Assigned: Getting getaddrinfo error in django

Tags: python, django, http

(base) C:\Users\Laksh\PythonProjects\Django\PIFORMS>python manage.py runserver example:8080
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you
 apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
March 13, 2019 - 23:51:35
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'PIFORMS.settings'
Starting development server at http://example:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

and my setting.py contains
**ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example']**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `example:8080`, hostname `example` can obviously not be resolved. That's why you are getting this error. `example` points to nowhere. You have to use a hostname that can be resolved to an internal IP (127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0) (like localhost). Consider using localhost or if you really want to use `example`, add it to your hosts file.

Here are some useful instructions about editing hosts file in windows

https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/18b10a14b2deb214dc4ce43a2d2e2992

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by indenting in the hosts file in windows:
The format is very important.

```
127.0.0.1     example.local
```